# polar form of unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, matrix-decomposition

Problem: Let $\mu$ be a unitary operator on  a finite dimensional complex inner product space. Show that there exists a self-adjoint linear operator $\rho$ such that $$\mu=e^{i\rho}$$.

I found this result in Steve Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra book.
I am able to see that the R.H.S.of the above equation is unitary but I am unable to construct a $\rho$ given a $\mu$.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups